# java.Security.NoSuchAlogirthmException

Tags: java, exception, keytool

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","spacesalt.store");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keystorePassword", "123456");

        HttpsURLConnection cons = null;
        URL url = null;

        String host ="https://www.google.com";
        url = new URL(host) ;

        cons = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection() ;
        cons.setReadTimeout(30000);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cons.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder() ;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            data.append(line +System.lineSeparator());
        }
}
```

The exception are - java.security.NoSuchalgorithmException ! I have created a keystore using keytool  named spacesalt.store and copied that spacesalt.store file into the project . I am using eclipse ! . Truly I have no idea about this at all . Need a dummy guide to solve it !

Comment: https://google.com is just an example for testing this code !

Comment: What does your KeyStore contain?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Also would help if you post the full exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I have reproduced your problem. I have generated a keystore and executed your code. After that I got an exception 
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:248)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:255)
```

I solved my issue setting the full path of the keystore:

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","full_path_to_keyStore_/spacesalt.store");
```

Access to the Keystore is done by calling to FileInputStream(property_value), so, you can also put your keystore in the folder from which you launch the application.

Comment: Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).